# Aligning strings in subsequent lines in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print something out in the console and want to make sure it is aligned properly. What I am getting is:

[image]

But what I want is for the Location.... to be all aligned. Not sure how to fix this. My code is:

```
print("{:>7}{:>60}".format(date, longitude))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string specifies a **minimum** width of 7 characters for date, but strings like "Sunday 14 December 2014 at 09.53 PM" are far longer and appear with their natural length. Replace 7 with an appropriate large number (at least the maximum possible length of the date string) to obtain the padding you want.

Comment: Thanks I just figured it out, but will keep it up for some other person new to python. Thanks.